# jquery ReferenceError: is not defined variable as array index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this error ReferenceError: postCssID is not defined

My script is working if I add js code inside my php file but not working if I use separated js file

in php is working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var offsets = offsets || new Array();
    offsets["<?=$pst_cssid?>"] = 5;
    $("#cmt-a-ii<?=$pst_cssid?>").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url: "<?=Url::to(['/comment/view-more'])?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: ({st: '<?=$pst_id?>', cssid: '<?=$pst_cssid?>', offset: offsets["<?=$pst_cssid?>"]}),
            success: function(result){
                $("#cmt-d-ii<?=$pst_cssid?>").append(result);
            }
        });
        offsets["<?=$pst_cssid?>"] += 5;
    });
</script>
```

But if I use separated js file is not working , the error is in this : offsets[postCssID]; in my php file I only declare variables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var postCssID = "<?=$pst_cssid?>";
    var postID = "<?=$pst_id?>";
    var urlLink = "<?=Url::to(['/comment/view-more'])?>";
</script>
```

I add path to my js file : `<script src="/sxct/js/ly-extra-script.js"></script>`

```
var offsets = offsets || new Array();
offsets[postCssID] = 5;
$("#cmt-a-ii"+postCssID).click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: urllink,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({st: postID, cssid: postCssID, offset: offsets[postCssID]}),
        success: function(result){
            $("#cmt-d-ii"+postCssID).append(result);
        }
    });
    offsets[postCssID] += 5;
});
```

Comment: Have you tested by putting script reference after `<script type="text/javascript">
    var postCssID = "<?=$pst_cssid?>";
    var postID = "<?=$pst_id?>";
    var urlLink = "<?=Url::to(['/comment/view-more'])?>";
</script>`

Comment: the same error "ReferenceError: postCssID is not defined"